# NSViewController initWithCoder - bundle has not been loaded

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a viewController in my storyboard that I have set up like below:

[image]

I am using the following code to load it programmatically.

```
-(AttributeViewController*)AttributeVC{
if(!_AttributeVC)
{
_AttributeVC = (AttributeViewController*)[self.storyboard 
instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAttribute"];

}

return _AttributeVC;
}
```

my app crashes with:

```
-[NSViewController initWithCoder:] could not instantiate an NSViewController for a
 nib in the "Attribute" bundle because the bundle has not been loaded.
```

Why is the view controller now trying to load the "Attribute" bundle that I don't have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the `storyboardWithName` reference in there as well... This worked for me

```
-(AttributeViewController*)AttributeVC{
if(!_AttributeVC)
{
_AttributeVC *attributeVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAttribute"];
}

return _AttributeVC;
}
```